# Select statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I try to create select query but still struggling. My aim is to receive total amount from colum AMOUNT, but for each row COLUMN_ID there must be at least one value less then 50 AND at least one value over 50. Total amount must be calculated by summarizing values where each one is less then 50, and this total amount must be less then 100.

1. Let say, I have values (90, 20, 40) - result should be SUM(AMOUNT) = 60
2. Let say, I have values (52, 70, 20, 40) - result should be SUM(AMOUNT) = 60
3. Let say, I have values (32, 7) - no result as there is no value over 50
4. Let say, I have values (60, 150) - no result as there is no value less then 50
5. Let say, I have values (75, 20, 40, 45) - no result as there is SUM(AMOUNT) = 105 so over 100

Select query I have created below just needs to add: sum(amount) of values where each one is less then 50

```
  SELECT COLUMN_ID, SUM(AMOUNT)
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY COLUMN_ID
  HAVING MIN(AMOUNT) < 50 AND MAX(AMOUNT) > 50 AND SUM(AMOUNT) < 100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT COLUMN_ID
      , SUM(case when ammount < 50 then ammount else 0 end ) sumsmall
 FROM T
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY COLUMN_ID
 HAVING SUM(case when ammount < 50 then ammount else 0 end ) > 0 
    and SUM(case when ammount > 50 then ammount else 0 end ) > 0
    and SUM(case when ammount < 50 then ammount else 0 end ) < 100
```

Comment: Vittore, thank you for your help. Unfortunately your select is not doing exactly what it suppose to do. I need to check first if there are any values grater than 50, if so, I need to sumarize all values less then 50, at the end I am checking whether total amount of values less than 50 is less then 100. Do you thing it is possible to do?

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much for your help, Happy Christmas :)